# .submit() in function works for 2 times

Tags: javascript

Here is my code

HTML

```
<form class="vfr-validate"
                          id="intl-numbers-list-form" action="${formAction}" method="post">                        


                    <div id="ion_error_non_eligible_chooser">          
                       <c:if test="${errorNonEligibleChooser == 'true'}">                            

                                              <p>
                                               <fmt:message key='com.vodafone.wlportal.portlet.ion.non.eligible.postpaid.crmt' bundle='${current_bundle}'/>
                                              </p>   
                                              <br>
                                              <a href="" class="btn btn-primary mr20">Vezi Oferte</a>                                                                                         

                       </c:if>
                    </div>

                          <div class="col-md-3">
                             <input id="input_phone_no" class="required width100 pull-left mb10 mobile_international" 
                                   type="text" maxlength="10"
                                   value="" name="phone_no">
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                             <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${fn:length(requestScope.listFnF) >= listFnFMax || errorNonEligibleChooser == 'true'}">
                                   <button disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary disabled" id="ion_add"
                                   data-wa="true" 
                                   data-wa-type="portlet"
                                   data-wa-portlet-name='<fmt:message key="com.vodafone.wlportal.portlet.ion.wa.data.wa.portlet.name" bundle="${global_properties_bundle }"/>'
                                   data-wa-portlet-facet='<fmt:message key="com.vodafone.wlportal.portlet.ion.wa.data.wa.portlet.facet.web" bundle="${global_properties_bundle }"/>'
                                   data-wa-portlet-action='<fmt:message key="com.vodafone.wlportal.portlet.ion.wa.data.wa.portlet.action.add" bundle="${global_properties_bundle }"/>'
                                   >
                                      <fmt:message key="com.vodafone.wlportal.portlet.ion.add.fnf" bundle="${current_bundle}" />
                                   </button>
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                   <button class="btn btn-primary browserion" id="ion_add" 
                                               onclick="return addFNFAction();"
                                   data-wa="true" 
                                   data-wa-type="portlet"
                                   data-wa-portlet-name='<fmt:message key="com.vodafone.wlportal.portlet.ion.wa.data.wa.portlet.name" bundle="${global_properties_bundle }"/>'
                                   data-wa-portlet-facet='<fmt:message key="com.vodafone.wlportal.portlet.ion.wa.data.wa.portlet.facet.web" bundle="${global_properties_bundle }"/>'
                                   data-wa-portlet-action='<fmt:message key="com.vodafone.wlportal.portlet.ion.wa.data.wa.portlet.action.add" bundle="${global_properties_bundle }"/>'
                                   >
                                      <fmt:message key="com.vodafone.wlportal.portlet.ion.add.fnf" bundle="${current_bundle}" />
                                   </button>

                                </c:otherwise>
                             </c:choose>
                          </div>



                    </div>                            

                 </form>
```

The JS function

```
function addFNFAction() {

    //console.log("addFNFAction");

    var form = $("#intl-numbers-list-form");
    if (form.valid() == true) {
        $('#ion_loader').show();
        $('#ion_add').attr("disabled", true);
        form.submit();
    }
}
```

The problem is that on IE 11, the form is making 2 times submit.
I have try to make the `onclick` in 2 ways `onclick="return addFNFAction();"` and also `onclick="addFNFAction();"`, the result is the same 2 submit is making.

Comment: can you share the generated html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the browser is doing a form submit and then your click handler is submitting the form once again. 
You should remove the onclick handler on button and add the onsubmit handler to your form tag.

Try this as as your opening form tag:-

```
<form class="vfr-validate" id="intl-numbers-list-form" onSubmit=addFNFAction method="post">
```

You will want to change the JS function to:-

```
function addFNFAction(event) {

        //console.log("addFNFAction");
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $("#intl-numbers-list-form");
        if (form.valid() == true) {
            $('#ion_loader').show();
            $('#ion_add').attr("disabled", true);
            form.submit();
        }

}
```

Comment: This works for me, but adding the `onSubmit` action instend of `onClick` also on button
`<button class="btn btn-primary browserion" id="ion_add" 
                                              onsubmit="return addFNFAction();"                              >
                                   </button>`

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are calling the jQuery's submit method which again calls the submit handlers. It could result in a recursive calls to the submit handler

Instead try to call the dom's `submit` method, also need to return `false` from the handler to stop the default action of the button click;

```
function addFNFAction() {

  //console.log("addFNFAction");

  var form = $("#intl-numbers-list-form");
  if (form.valid() == true) {
    $('#ion_loader').show();
    $('#ion_add').attr("disabled", true);
    form[0].submit();
  }
  return false;
}
```